# AngularJS ng-table with pagination: no rows displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ngtable

I'm trying to use ng-table (http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/) in a web app based onto Typescript and AngularJS. I just have to display in a paged table some 50-500 items at most, all loaded at once from the server; so I'll what I need is client-side paging of my controller's data. Yet, no row is displayed when my data are loaded, unless I totally disable paging.

I made a **plunkr** which reproduces the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0hCSMm03L8iHwePccm7x?p=preview

As I'm using Typescript (but there is no definition for this lib right now), I've shaped my example code like a typical outcome of the TS compiler, but apart from that, I followed the paging example in the ng-table website. Just click the button to fill the controller's data.

**Update**: by examining the ng-table source I managed to force the refresh by calling `tableParams.total(...)` and then `tableParams.reload()` after I have filled my data array; yet, there is no trace of this code in the samples so I'm feeling a bit wrong about this.

Comment: Yes you are using the correct way to do this! This is a little bit late but here is the Typescript definition for ngTable http://pastebin.com/q6zCGKd4

Answer (score 0):

I used that too (i.e. update the total and reload the table). I reasoned that I had created an instance of a table and then I needed to update the instance with the new information. hth